# SwiftUI - Firebase Authentication - Environmental Object Doesn't Update on Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I followed [this tutorial](https://benmcmahen.com/authentication-with-swiftui-and-firebase/) to add Firebase user authentication to my SwiftUI project. When the user signs in or signs up, the sign in view is supposed to dissapear, and text displaying "Login Successful" should appear instead. However, this does not happen. It seems like the login / sign up process works, but the views don't change, and I suspect it may a problem with the `EnvironmentalObject`. Does anybody have some ideas about why this is happening? Thank you!

Here is some of my code -

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
...
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(SessionStore()))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
...
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

  @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

  func getUser () {
      session.listen()
  }

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
          if (session.session == nil) {
              SignInView()
          } else {
              Text("Login successful!")
          }
    }.onAppear {
        self.getUser()
    }
  }
}
```

**SignInView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SignInView : View {

    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var loading = false
    @State var error = false

    @State var signInWorked = ""

    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    func signIn () {
        loading = true
        error = false
        session.signIn(email: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            self.loading = false
            if error != nil {
                self.error = true
            } else {
                self.email = ""
                self.password = ""
                self.signInWorked = "Signed In!"
            }
        }
    }

    func signUp () {
        loading = true
        error = false
        session.signUp(email: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            self.loading = false
            if error != nil {
                self.error = true
            } else {
                self.email = ""
                self.password = ""
                self.signInWorked = "Signed In!"
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Email Adress", text: $email)
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            if (error) {
                Text("ahhh crap")
            }
            Button(action: signIn) {
                Text("Sign in")
            }
            Button(action: signUp) {
               Text("Sign Up")
            }
            Text(signInWorked)
        }
    }
}
```

**SessionStore.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Combine

class SessionStore : ObservableObject {
var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
var session: User? { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

func listen () {
    // monitor authentication changes using firebase
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {
            // if we have a user, create a new user model
            print("Got user: \(user)")
            self.session = User(
                uid: user.uid,
                displayName: user.displayName,
                email: user.email)
        } else {
            // if we don't have a user, set our session to nil
            self.session = nil
        }
    }
}

func signUp(
    email: String,
    password: String,
    handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback
    ) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
}

func signIn(
    email: String,
    password: String,
    handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback
    ) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
}

func signOut () -> Bool {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.session = nil
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}

func unbind () {
    if let handle = handle {
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }
}
}
```

**User.swift**

```
import Foundation

class User {
var uid: String
var email: String?
var displayName: String?

init(uid: String, displayName: String?, email: String?) {
    self.uid = uid
    self.email = email
    self.displayName = displayName
}
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem too. The app works correctly in simulator and device but not into the Canvas

Comment: Well, in my case, it occurs in all three. The sign in is successful, but the view doesn't dissapear.

Comment: yes the same for me. The sign works properly but the view doesn't disappear in canvas (simulator and device work).

Comment: pod 'CombineFirebase/Auth' will drastically simplify this.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the property wrapper `@Published` to your `var session` in SessionStore ensure that all views using it are refreshed when it changes. So change

`var session: User? { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}`

to

**`@Published`**`var session: User? { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}`

See here for more info: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Answer (score 0):

you can try this example [iOS - swiftUI - Firebase Login complete setup](https://github.com/Balaviknesh/iOS-SwiftUI-Firebase-Login-Example)
this works  perfectly and also does the same as you required. In this example after the login process is done in presenter modal, so when login is successful, it calls back the defined function and dismiss the login page. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer specifically for those who are only not seeing it in canvas, but it works in simulator and device; you have to go to the YourView_Previews: section of your code (at the bottome) and add .environmentObject(SessionStore()) to the view being called in the preview (If your in ContentView.swift then it would be ContentView().environmentObject(SessionStore()) **in the body of the Preview**

Answer (score 0):

Ok this worked for me: if the @Published var isn't working and is only taking you to the HomeView (view you specify to go to if a user is signed in), you need to add a:

```
    func () { 
        session.signOut()
    }
```

put this in your HomeView()(not the body, but the struct) and create a signOut button that calls this func -- the problem is that your user remains signed in until you sign them out, and this easy fix should do it.